# Eclipse codan support for C++11 initializer list as function parameters

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11

When a function is expected to accept parameter of a container type (or anything that can be implicitly initialized by an `initializer_list`, like

```
void someFunc(std::vector<int> args);
```

And in the calling site, below code will be marked as errornous

```
someFunc({1,2,3});
```

The eclipse CDT parser (known as codan) considers the function call as `invalid arguments`, and the CDT version is already latest one (8.8.1).

Is there any workaround to suppress the error? It's not a good fix the suppress the whole group of invalid argument cases.

Answer (score 0):

How about making it explicit?
    `someFunc(static_cast<std::vector<int> >({1,2,3}));`

Comment: ops, this is more messy

Comment: FWIW, `static_cast` didn't work for me (codan didn't like it, and neither did `gcc 5.4`. C-style cast did work though, like: `someFunc((static_cast<std::vector<int> >){1,2,3});`